# Grow LVM on LUKS Logical Volume

Tags: arch-linux, partition, lvm, luks, cryptsetup

so I'm on ArchLinux and have the following setup

```
└─sda3              8:3    0 297.3G  0 part  
  └─cryptolvm     254:0    0 297.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─mandos-swap 254:1    0     8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─mandos-root 254:2    0    25G  0 lvm   /
    └─mandos-home 254:3    0 264.3G  0 lvm   /home
```

where I am using LVM on LUKS. What I'd like to do is to expand `mandos-root` to roughly `50G` by taking `25G` from `mandos-home`. I found this article https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS#Enlarge_LVM_on_LUKS on the wiki but I'm not convinced that my setupis is the same. Can somebody help me figure out how to move space from one logical volume to another or whether this is even possible?

Comment: As long as you're just shrinking/growing LV, leaving PV size untouched, this has nothing whatsoever to do with LUKS. Encryption is transparent to higher layers, you can proceed as if it did not exist (shrink home, grow root).

Comment: Boot from a distribution medium. Unlock the LUKS volume. `vgchange -aay` to activate the LVM logical volumes. Do not mount the filesystems. Shrink the filesystem on `/dev/mapper/mandos-home`. (This cannot be done if it is mounted, that's why you need to boot from an installation medium.) Shrink the LVM logical volume `mandos-home`. Expand the LVM logical volume `mandos-root`; if needed, expand the fileystem on `/dev/mapper/mandos-root`. Reboot into your installation.

Comment: Do you benefit from having `/` and `/home`? If you run out of space again you'll have to repeat the process. Have you considered just having `/`?